# rails joining two tables together using has oen and has many

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm trying to link two models together

currently, I have tickets for events.

in the event model, I'm under the understanding that one event `has one` or more tickets so that would be a `has many`?

and in the tickets table, it would have one event?

In the tickets table, I have the `event_id` column.

Basically what I've wanting to have is the ability to type `event.tickets.each` for example to return all the tickets in the event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
event.rb model

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tickets
end

ticket.rb model

class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
end
```

to fetch tickets of event do like below

```
event  = Event.first
event.tickets.each do |ticket|
  puts ticket.inspect
end
```

Answer (score 0):

in ticket model add `has_many :events`
in event model add `belongs_to :ticket`

your events table should have a ticket_id foreign key.

this way you can do event.ticket
and also ticket.events

that is all :)